# How to read a string file from second line in C?

Tags: c++, c

This code reads characters in a file and calculates length of characters. How i can read from second line and ignore read from first line?

this is part of my code:

```
    int lenA = 0;
    FILE * fileA;
    char holder;
    char *seqA=NULL;
    char *temp=NULL;

    fileA=fopen("d:\\str1.fa", "r");
    if(fileA == NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening 'str1.fa'\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((holder=fgetc(fileA)) != EOF) {
    lenA++;
    temp=(char*)realloc(seqA,lenA*sizeof(char));
    if (temp!=NULL) {
        seqA=temp;
        seqA[lenA-1]=holder;
    }
    else {
        free (seqA);
        puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
        exit (1);
    }
}
cout<<"Length seqA is: "<<lenA<<endl;
fclose(fileA);
```

Comment: Read character by character until `\n` is encountered, then read in the 2nd line.

Comment: The only way to read from the second line is to read the first line and ignore it, then continue reading the second and subsequent lines and process them as required.  Consider using `fgets()`.

Comment: You're code is pretty much C with the only C++ facility being `cout`. You should stick to _one_ of both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a counter of how many `\n` you have seen,and when `==1` goto read from 2nd line.

```
    int line=0;
    while((holder=fgetc(fileA)) != EOF) {
     if(holder == '\n') line++;
     if(holder == 1) break; /* 1 because count start from 0,you know */
    }
    if(holder == EOF) {
     //error:there's no a 2nd
    }       
   while((holder=fgetc(fileA)) != EOF) { 
    // holder is contents begging from 2nd line
   }
```

You can make it more simple by using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html):

Make one call and ignore it(by don't discard the result-value,for error-checking);

Make second call, and begging reading from this.

NOTE: I'm considering C language here.

Comment: @milad_b: Just use `getline()` function. It's C++'s equivalent(speaking roughly) to C's `fgets()`,except that `getline()`didn't put `\n` into buffer.But you can add it yourself,if you need of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tiny mistakes about the last answer.
I corrected and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TEMP_PATH "/FILEPATH/network_speed.txt"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(TEMP_PATH, "r");

    char holder;

    int line=0;
    while((holder=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(holder == '\n') line++;
        if(line == 1) break; /* 1 because count start from 0,you know */
    }
    if(holder == EOF) {
        printf("%s doesn't have the 2nd line\n", fp);
        //error:there's no a 2nd
    }       
    while((holder=fgetc(fp)) != EOF && (holder != '\n' )) { 
        putchar(holder);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: There is a defect of this code, when I set `line==0` to show the first line, the first chractor will be lost