# what mistake am I doing in finding out Array Index Percentages in C

Tags: arrays, c

Here's the question given:
An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. In this challenge, create an array 'A' of size of 6, and read the values from stdin. Iterate the array to calculate the 75% value of the even indices value and 25% value of the odd indices value and store them in an array 'B' of size 6 and diplay the sum of even indices and odd indices from the array 'B'.

Input Format

integer integer integer integer integer integer integer

Constraints

element valuve should be >0 and <100

Output Format

float float

Sample Input 0

```
6
10
20
30
40
50
60
```

Sample Output 0

```
67.50
30.00
```

Code I wrote was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int A[6], i;
    float B[6], esum = 0, osum = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            B[i] = 0.75 * A[i];
        } else {
            B[i] = 0.25 * A[i];
        }
    }
    

    
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            esum = B[i] + esum;
        } else {
            osum = B[i]+ osum;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%.2f\n%.2f", esum, osum);
    

    return 0;
}
```

And heres what i got

```
Testcase 0
Your code did not pass this test case.

Input (stdin)

6
10
20
30
40
50
60
Your Output (stdout)

49.50
22.50
Expected Output

67.50
30.00
Compiler Message

Wrong Answer
```

Pardon me if theres anything wrong in the way i did and help

Comment: Your input has an extra `6` which you are reading as part of the array data. I'm guessing it is meant to be read and interpreted as the number of values to read.

Comment: ...and assume (or check) that this isn't *more* than `6`, the size of the arrays you were told, and use it for the iteration.

Comment: Aside: Do you really need to iterate through the array 3 times? I reckon one loop would do the job.

Comment: The `6` that precedes the input is the number of values in the A array. It is not a part of the array. The values in B are `(10+30+50)*.75` which is `67.50` and `(20+40+60)*.25` which is `30`. But the code isn't reading the initial 6 as a count, which is what's causing the problem.  It needs to treat the first value as the count.  Then it either needs to handle the given count, or else give an error if it isn't 6.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is working properly. You just need to start reading the file from the second value, so it skips the first `6` number, as it is not an input number but the length of an array.
Here is an answer on how to read the file from the second line: [How to read a string file from second line in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376868/how-to-read-a-string-file-from-second-line-in-c)